# How do I pass variables between methods in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, instance-variables

I am trying to build a program, but I realized I can't access a certain variable because it's created in another method.

How do I transfer a variable to another method?

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
namespace Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the "text" variable and use it
            label1.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally you'd return something from a method. Or perhaps the method would assign a value to a property of its class, which you could then access. It all depends on context. If you want a more definitive answer, show your existing code and explain exactly what you're trying to do

Comment: You can read about methods with parameters and return values.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your question. What you asking for is unclear/something missing. What is your goal & difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, dev env, data types & expected result, as well as to share more or less code (no screenshot), samples, images or sketches of screens, & user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example has a *Form* named `Form1` that has a *Button* named `button1`, a *TextBox* named `textbox1` and a *Label* named `label1`.

The scenario you are attempting is:

1. user enters some text into `textbox1`
2. user clicks on `button1`, this will save the current value from `textbox1`
3. user clicks on `label1`, this will display the value that was stored in the previous step

It is important to understand that in this scenario we are not trying to *pass a value between 2 methods* because the button click and the label click can occur independently of each other, so really this is like the memory store (M+) and memory recall (MR) buttons on calculator.
To achieve this *storage* you should create an *instance variable* (sometimes referred to as a *member variable*) on the `Form1` class, this will be accessible to the other methods on the same instance of the `Form1` class.

> See [Working with Instance and Local variables](https://tekslate.com/instance-and-local-variable-in-c-sharp-net-with-examples) for a practical explanation

1. Create a *field* or a *property* to *store* the value, for your specific example either would work, however to become familiar with C# techniques I would recommend you start with a property, as that better encapsulates your scenario of *storing the value for later use* and later to potentially augment how and where the value is actually stored.

   > See [What is the difference between a field and a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/1690217)
   >  for a healthy discussion
   > Until you need to change the implementation, you can simply use an [Auto-Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

   ```
    public string StoredText { get; set; }
   ```
2. Now in the *click* event handler of `button1` we can *set* the value of the `StoredText` property on the `Form1` instance

   ```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.StoredText = textBox1.Text;
    }
   ```

   > *set* is a term we use for saving a value into a property in c#
   > Note the use of the `this` keyword, it is optional in this case, or can be *inferred* by the compliler, it indicates that we want to reference a member on the *instance* of the class, not a variable that might have the same name within the same method scope of the line of code that is executing.
3. Finally in the *click* event handler of `label1` we can *get* the value that was previously stored in the `StoredText` property in the `Form1` instance.

   ```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the "StoredText" variable and use it
        label1.Text = this.StoredText;
    }
   ```

   > *get* is a term we use for accessing a value from a property in c#
   > `this` is not required, but can be helpful to understand that we are accessing a member that is outside of the current method scope.

Together this looks something like:

```
namespace Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>Saved value from see <see href="textBox1"/></summary>
        public string StoredText { get; set; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.StoredText = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the "StoredText" variable and use it
            label1.Text = this.StoredText;
        }
    }
}
```

---

What you may not have noticed is that `textBox1` and `label1` are themselves infact `instance variables` that are initialized in a separate code file when `InitializeComponent()` is executed in the *constructor*.
For this reason you do not *need* to store the value at all and you could simply re-write the client event handler for `button1` to write directly to `label`:

```
label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

---

It is possible to pass variables directly between methods without an intermediary store, this is a lesson for another day and will involve `return` statements and/or `parameters` on your methods.
In this scenario however, neither `return` or additional parameters on these methods cannot be used because these are *event handlers* that need a specific method signature to operate as expected.

Comment: This is a direct answer, but perhaps something should be said about [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)? It is not common in the Windows Forms world, but perhaps it should be (especially for larger projects).

Comment: Thanks @PeterMortensen I'm hoping that by guiding OP into the use of Properties over Fields is enough at this stage, but as a strong MVVM advocate, even in Forms I should be a little more forceful on this issue. I was worried my personal bias would get in the way of offering practical advice without overwhelming OP.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. It is a common practice in object-oriented programming to have private variables in a class, in order to share states. Add a variable in your class. It will be available in all methods and can be used to shared data between them (this is one approach of many):

```
namespace Example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string inputText { get; set; }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            inputText = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the "text" variable and use it
            label1.Text = inputText;
        }
    }
}
```